# Python join (NameError: name 'join' is not defined)

Tags: python, join

Hello there is a function in my companies code that I don't understand. It does uses join without a preceding string object. Whenever I try to mimick this behaviour in my python shell I get the error:

```
 (NameError: name 'join' is not defined)
```

Which makes sense since join is not supposed to work that way

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import time
import math

def doit(reservations, operationFrom, operationTo):
    ret = [(operationFrom, operationTo, 0)]
    for res in reservations:
        ret = join(res, ret, sum)
    return ret
```

How come the join doesn't throw an error? Isn't join supposed to be used like so for example:

```
"fkasndfk".join(['x','y','z'])
```

Comment: There's a `join` function defined in your company's code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your company's code has a bug and the `join` call will produce an exception if it's ever executed (`reservations` could be empty!), or `join` is  defined somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os.path import join
```

try importing this library. it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).